# Remove Duplicate Records Based on NA Count

Tags: r, filter, group-by, duplicates

I have a data set with a primary key called ID.  The primary key is duplicated across multiple rows.  The duplicate rows have different amounts of missing information represented as NA's.

I want to group by the primary key ID, then retain the record that has the most information, and the least amount of NA's.

I've gotten the below code to get me grouped_by for the duplicates, but I'm struggling to remove the rows with the most NA's.

With the data below, I would like to retain the first row, while dropping the second and third because they are missing more values than the first row.

Row 1 is missing only 1 value and should be retained, while rows 2-3 are missing 2 and 3 values respectively.

```
dupes = df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(n()>1)

ID   Product   Cost   Date   Name    State
1      X       NA     2019   John    CA
1      NA      15     NA     Bill    GA
1      NA      NA     2019   NA      CA
2      Y       15     2019   Chris   CA
```

Comment: Isn't this `df%>% filter(!is.na(Product))`

Comment: Fair point, but no.  I'll edit the post to illustrate, but the data set is 30 columns, with a large number of combinations of missing values.  Filtering by NA on a single column will not do it.

Comment: Let's say you have NA count of 10 15 20 (among the 30 columns) for ID 1, which one would you keep

Comment: I would want to keep the 10, drop the 15 and 20.

Comment: Try `df %>% mutate(n = rowSums(is.na(.))) %>% group_by(ID) %>% slice(which.min(n))`

Comment: It's running.  Taking a little while, large file of a couple million records.  Reading up on the function, slice seems exactly what I needed.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to create a condition based on the number of `NA`s in each row i.e. after grouping by 'ID',`slice` the rows that have the minimum number of `NA` elements

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   mutate(n = rowSums(is.na(.))) %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   slice(which.min(n)) %>% 
   select(-n)
```

---

Or a similar logic with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[df[, .I[which.min(Reduce(`+`, lapply(.SD, is.na)))], ID]$V1]
```

Comment: That did the trick.  akrun's recommendation seems very similar using slice, but it was taking a lot longer.  Yours ran much faster.  Thank you very much for the help!